# Deserializing JSON in C# : object vs array

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm not a C# guy, but I'm writing a web service where I generate JSON data and I'm trying to help the guy writing the C# client parse the JSON.

Here's the situation: I return objects where some properties are objects and others are arrays. The client is generic and doesn't know in advance of parsing which properties and objects and which are arrays.

Is there a way to parse arbitrary JSON (whether array or object) without knowing in advance? For example these don't work

```
JArray.Parse(...)
JObject.Parse(...)
```

because they require advance knowledge of the type.

Ideally there's something like

```
Json.Parse(...)
```

that spits out an array or an object depending on the JSON.

Comment: `dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);` should work for any valid json

Comment: I always recommend deserialization to a stronly-typed object.  Any reason this can't be done?

Comment: @ErikPhilips `Any reason this can't be done` the question is about this.

Comment: Why would the properties be either objects or arrays... this kind of mutation is weird, and a clear example of duck-typing. If some property can contain an array I would send an array, period. Can you explain the benefit of this property mutation? And why no other API out there (twitter, fb-api, gplus, etc) mutates in such way?

Comment: It's not a single property that's either an object or array. It's that some properties are objects and others are arrays. For example a host has a single hostname but an array of IP addresses.

Comment: Ideally we can deserialize the JSON without the client having to know all about the schema. Fine with doing the C# equivalent of instanceof (Java) once we have the deserialized object/array.

Comment: @LB The question does not demonstrate any knowledge of strongly-typed deserialization.  Dynamic, Object, Anonymous, JObject, JArray are not strongly typed, as deserialization of a string does not guarantee a property will exist at compile time, instead it produces a weak type that requires run-time checking.  The advantage of deserializing to a strong-typed class is that the deserialization cause throw an exception if required properties don't exist, instead of checking every required property (even in nested classes which can get ugly).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Points well-taken. For what it's worth, I wrote a Java binding that applies the strong-typing strategy you describe, and I agree that it's a good approach. In this case the C# developer here prefers working with the weak types, and I just needed a way to help him get over the object/array hump given his preference.

Comment: Then the answer is definitely correct in this case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/):

```
 dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

or

```
 var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JToken;
```

or

```
var jObj = JToken.Parse(json);
```